# Why I get double double-quote on output CSV file in Scriptella?

Tags: java, oracle, csv, double-quotes, scriptella

I'm facing the following issue.

With an etl configuration file I load some data from a `Oracle` DB Table than I export these data to a `CSV` file.
However, when a field contains double quote (") this character is duplicated.

I'll explain with a simple example:

The field DESCRIPTION in the table NAMES contain the following:
**This is a "description" of my name**

When I use the CSV driver to export the the content of this table I see the following data in the CSV:
**This is a ""description"" of my name**

ETL conf:

> <connection id="out-names" driver="csv" url="names.csv">
>       quote=
>       encoding=UTF-8
>       trim=true
>       null_string=
>   </connection>
>   ...
>   <query connection-id="db">
>       SELECT NAME,DESCRIPTION FROM NAMES;
>       <script connection-id="out-names">
>          $1;$2
>       </script>
>   </query>

Any help on this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely correct, 2 x double quotes means one double quote in CSV terms, thus this is correct...

```
123,"This is a string",456,13-Feb-2013,"This is ""Another"" String"
```

Where the second string is has "escaped" double quotes in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output content unescaped, try using a text driver instead:

```
<connection id="out-names" driver="text" url="names.csv">
</connection>
...

<query connection-id="db">
    SELECT NAME,DESCRIPTION FROM NAMES;
    <script connection-id="out-names">
        $1;$2
    </script>
</query>
```